# Rewriting a Boolean AND-OR as OR-AND

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have an expression `a'b'c + a'bc + ab'c + abc'` in AND-OR and I need to write as OR-AND. Simply applying De Morgans doesnt work as it results in:

`(a+b+c')(a+b'+c')(a'+b+c')(a'+b'+c)`

The truth table for this is all `1`. Should I pick a value and use the Distributive property and keep repeating?

I tried distributing out the original to get:

```
a'(b'c+bc) + a(b'c+bc')
a'(c(b'+b)) + a(b'c+bc')
a'(c(1)) + a(b'c+bc')
```

But thats as far as I have gotten at this point